# Filtering footprints to given bounding box

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm trying to get footprints with landuse tag within sample bounding box with query below:

```
[out:json][timeout:180];
(
  way(poly:"50.859515 18.568600 50.859515 18.580753 50.862946 18.580753 50.862946 18.568600 50.859515 18.568600")["landuse"];(._;>;);
  relation(poly:"50.859515 18.568600 50.859515 18.580753 50.862946 18.580753 50.862946 18.568600 50.859515 18.568600")["landuse"];(._;>;);
);
out body;
```

Unfortunately, returned ways are out of my bounding box, as shown on the picture below (bbox is approximately red square) so the question is how to filter results to retrieve data only in my bounding box range?

[image]

Comment: bbox should be <bbox-query s="51.0" w="7.0" n="52.0" e="8.0"/> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Bounding_box_clauses_.28.22bbox_query.22.2C_.22bounding_box_filter.22.29

Comment: Hi, could you help me with implementing this to my query? I've swapped ("poly...") part with bbox coordinates but nothing changed

Comment: Duplicate post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/72978/filtering-footprints-to-given-bounding-box

Comment: This works as designed by the way.